# Why span behaves like a block element?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I don't understand why span element has width like a block element. I've set almost all elements 'display:inline-flex'. They must be created as inline elements. Maybe I don't set this display value to some necessary element

[image]

```
<form className="flex justify-center grow p-[30px]">
    <div className="inline-flex flex-col gap-[45px]">
        <div className="w-[850px] gap-[45px] inline-flex flex-col">
            <div className="inline-flex flex-col gap-[10px]"><span className="text-textColor_base text-[18px]">Range of balance percentage</span>
                <div className="inline-flex "><input
                    className="border-input pl-[5px] w-[110px] h-[45px] rounded-l-[5px] border-l-[1px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                    placeholder="Min(%)" type="number" name="balancePercentage_min"><input
                    className="border-input pl-[5px] w-[110px] h-[45px] rounded-r-[5px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                    placeholder="Min(%)" type="number" name="balancePercentage_min"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="inline-flex flex-col gap-[10px]"><span className="text-textColor_base text-[18px]">Range of leverage</span>
                <div className="inline-flex "><input
                    className="border-input pl-[5px] w-[110px] h-[45px] rounded-l-[5px] border-l-[1px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                    placeholder="Min(x)" type="number" name="leverage_min"><input
                    className="border-input pl-[5px] w-[110px] h-[45px] rounded-r-[5px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                    placeholder="Min(x)" type="number" name="leverage_min"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="inline-flex flex-col gap-[10px]"><span className="text-textColor_base text-[18px]">Range of duration of transactions</span>
                <div className="inline-flex "><input
                    className="border-input pl-[5px] w-[110px] h-[45px] rounded-l-[5px] border-l-[1px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                    placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="durationOfTransactions_min"><input
                    className="border-input pl-[5px] w-[110px] h-[45px] rounded-r-[5px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                    placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="durationOfTransactions_min"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="inline-flex flex-col gap-[10px]"><span className="text-textColor_base text-[18px]">Delay between transactions</span>
                <div className="inline-flex "><input
                    className="border-input pl-[5px] w-[110px] h-[45px] rounded-l-[5px] border-l-[1px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                    placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="delayTransactions_min"><input
                    className="border-input pl-[5px] w-[110px] h-[45px] rounded-r-[5px] border-r-[1px] bg-inputColor_background text-textColor_base"
                    placeholder="Min(Hours)" type="number" name="delayTransactions_min"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Start"
               className="grow-0 rounded-[5px] bg-commonColor_secondary text-textColor_base"></div>
    <div></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I've set almost all elements `display:inline-flex`

There's your issue. A child element of a flex container creates a box that's a flex item. Flex-items are blockified - so the computed value of `display` for the `span` elements is `block`. The width value of a `display:block` element will have the desired effect.

Comment: What the elements of those I need to replace with 'display: block' to resolve this issue?